# Sharing debuger from Graph API not working

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I am sending a POST request to the API with data as on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects

```
"id" : <domain>,
"scrape": True,
"access_token" : <token>
```

But in response I get an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '<domain>' does not exist, 
               cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this
               operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at ...",
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33, 
    "fbtrace_id": "A4szfMq_LpEo8ne_xipo3ky" 
  },
  "__fb_trace_id__":"An9T1FjDJD2",
  "__www_request_id__":"A4szfMq_LpEo8ne_xipo3ky"
}
```

Comment: What is `<domain>`?

Comment: @WizKid `<domain>` - this is domain name(can be any). For example I use google.com

Comment: google.com is not a URL. The documentation say it needs to be a URL. Try `https://www.google.com`

Comment: @WizKid oh, it's work! you make my day! thanks